# Firebase database rules version 2 - Getting Started with your Transport Tracker

Tags: android, firebase

I am struggling on my way through [setting up the Google Transport Tracker](https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/transport-tracker/start). In the guide it says that in Firebase (...)

3. Set the default rules setting for read to true:

```
    "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null"
    }
```

while the rules (version 2) it writes

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Does (allow read) mean (.read = true) and do I need to add anything from the guide?

Comment: Your first example is showing rules for Realtime Database, and your second example is showing rules for Firestore.  They are completely different database products with different rules languages.  Which one are you working with?

Comment: @DougStevenson Given the article I added a link to, OP is working with RTDB.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. It turned out that I had to switch a selector on the page from defaul Cloud Firestore to Real Database.